# Iptables Tor only

Tags: iptables, tor

How do I block all connections except Tor using Iptables?

I tried the following script but it didn't work, nothing is loading, including Tor

```
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1:65000 --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9050 --dport 1:65000 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o enp4s0 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 43 -j ACCEPT
```